# What is causing the empty area to the right of the image on this web-page?

Tags: html, css, image, viewer

I am trying to display a div element that contains image element and shows scrollbars when either the image is or grows too large to fit on the screen.  This div element is contained in a parent div that is used to horizontally center its contents, which besides the div and its image, already mentioned, are two other div elements, one on the left side of the image-div and one on right side of the image-div.

However, when the image is not wide enough an empty area shows on the right side of the image.

I don't want to increase the image size.  I want the div that encloses the image to shrink to fit the image when the image is displayed with a width less than 100%.  When the image is 100% or grater then I want the parent div to grow, but no larger than fits the screen.  Specifically, I don't want the image to grow so large that it causes the web-page to begin scrolling off the bottom of the page.

Here is code that shows what I'm talking about.

```css
div {
  border: thin solid black;
  position: relative;
}

div:first-of-type { 
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

div:first-of-type > div { 
  padding: unset;
}

div:first-of-type > div:first-of-type {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

div:first-of-type > div:first-of-type > div { display: table-cell }

div:first-of-type > div:first-of-type > div:nth-of-type(2) {
  overflow: scroll;
  background-color: gray
}
div:first-of-type > div:first-of-type > div,
div:first-of-type > div:last-of-type > div {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0
}

img { width: 50%;
      min-width: 50px;
      min-height: 50px;
    }
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div><div><</div></div>
    <div>
      <img  src="https://townsquare.media/site/341/files/2012/11/tumblr_ls6ujhB6wV1qfq9oxo1_5001.jpg?w=980&amp;q=75">
    </div>
    <div><div>></div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

At the bottom of this question are two pictures, the first is what I see when I run the code in the snippet and the second is what I want to see the code produce.  Notice that the gray area is gone in the second picture and the box enclosing the image and controls has shrunk to fit the content and is centered horizontally.

Can someone please help with the css or html code.  There isn't any javascript, and likely won't need to be any.

[image: what I see]

[image: what I'd like see]

Incidentally, when this part is working, I'm going to add the SpryMap plug-in to allow the user to scrolled the image when it is larger than the img element's area.  However, when the image's zoom level is under 100% then I want the image to be shown centered on the screen between the < and > controls,  without scrollbars unless the image causes an overflow to occur, all one line.

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of overflow: scroll try this: overflow-x: hidden and overflow-y: auto

Comment: Thank for replying, but changing the overflow scroll options as you suggest doesn't remove the empty area, it only removes that scrollbars.  The > on the right side, doesn't move in against the image, and the image and arrows aren't centered.

Comment: but you stated in your css  definition for img html element to occupy 50% of the space of its container DIV element so  the img will never occupy the whole parent space. Please reconsider your decision

Comment: Thanks AlanM, I took another look at my coding with respect to your information, and came up with a  way that works by converting % zoom values to px height and width values, and then extend my code to manage the scrollbars based on the initial image dimensions when loaded and the calculated height and width when the zoom level is changed, which is inline with Buttered_Toast suggestion.    Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/howardb1/full/ExjNBjO) example that solves the empty space problem.  The solutions addresses the gap between the right side of the image and the vertical scrollbar to the right of the image, but this is only really a problem because the overflow/overflow-y is set to scroll rather than auto/hidden.  The gap also prevents the > right-pointing arrow from being against the right side of the image and the proper horizontal centering of the image and surrounding controls. These problems are solved when the image's height/width are assigned pixel values, not % values.

```
        function inputChange( This ) {
          if( This.checkValidity() ) {
            var img       = document.querySelector( 'img' );
            var div       = img.parentElement;
            var liveStyle = window.getComputedStyle( div );
            var maxHeight = parseInt( liveStyle.getPropertyValue( 'max-height' ) );
            var maxWidth  = parseInt( liveStyle.getPropertyValue( 'max-width' ) );
            var v         = ~~This.value;
            var h         = ( img.naturalHeight * v ) / 100;
            var w         = ( img.naturalWidth  * v ) / 100;

            div.style.height =
            img.style.height = h + 'px';
            div.style.width  =
            img.style.width  = w + 'px';

            div.style.overflowX = ( ( w <= maxWidth  ) ? 'hidden' : 'scroll' );
            div.style.overflowY = ( ( h <= maxHeight ) ? 'hidden' : 'scroll' );

          }
        }
```